# How to Place an Image in Swing GUI when working from a Repository

Tags: image, swing, user-interface, repository, imageicon

I'm trying to display an image in a Java Swing GUI. I'm working in a team repository so I created a new source folder in the project to store my image. I've done the following code and it works when I run it off my laptop. The image doesn't appear for my team however on their machines and I'm guessing it has something to do with the image path (My repository location is a folder on my desktop). How can I reference the image so that the team can see it. We're using Tortoise SVN and Eclipse. Thanks

```
JLabel logolbl = new JLabel("New label");
    logolbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Echo Repo\\trunk\\Imagery\\echoLogo200.jpg"));
    logolbl.setBounds(10, 118, 202, 191);
    contentPane.add(logolbl);

    JLabel lblAtcLogIn = new JLabel("ATC Log In");
    lblAtcLogIn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    lblAtcLogIn.setBounds(174, 26, 110, 30);
    contentPane.add(lblAtcLogIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to load it on different machines, you will need to save the image file as an embedded resource into your jar.

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            images
                 echoLogo200.jpg
```

Your IDE should package the image into the jar. Then you need to read the image from the class path.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/echoLogo200.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);   // will throw exception is path is incorrect
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great but I don't know how to add the image to the jar. The IDE didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Did you put the image into a package inside the `src`?